# Opening :terminal window in new buffer

Tags: terminal, terminal-buffer

When I type `:terminal` to vim8.1, it splits the window and I use it split window. I want to open a new buffer and open the terminal inside it. Basically, like neovim's terminal emulator. Is there a way to do like this?

Comment: Please read the documentation for the `:terminal` command

Comment: It is a new buffer...

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Replying with "Please read the docs" and "Is such and such too simple" is condescending. Please help without making others feel belittled, and include full answers rather than telling people to read the manual.

Comment: @apostl3pol look, in the spirit of *teach men how to fish* I am merely pointing out where to find the documentation about the `:term` command. It's not only about this option, but other related options you might want to consider if you want to know what `:term`.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Of course. A good approach is to link to the doc, but also include an example. Vim has great documentation, but it doesn’t have the searchability that Stackexchange does.

Comment: @apostl3pol I disagree. Once you got known to the documentation, You know what to look for. And it has great capabilities to search. See `:h helphelp` and also possibly `:h help-summary`. I know, because I have contributed quite a bit of the documentation. And after all those are text files, you could also simply grep those if wanted. In summary, I think search capabilities of Vim help files are much better (and always fit to the current version) than to use a search engine like Google or search using Stackoverflow

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to Christian Brabandt, `:ter ++curwin` was the thing that I want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `call term_open()` instead. if you want to open shell in current win, it is:

```
call term_start($SHELL, {'curwin' : 1})
```

BTW, if you think this command is too long, you can create custom command:

```
command! Terminal call term_start($SHELL, {'curwin' : 1)
```

Comment: Is `:terminal ++curwin` too simple?